# Parser as main file?

Tags: java, parsing, program-entry-point

I am trying to write a big system that inputs data from a text file, and has a parser file. So, do I have to write a main file that would call the parser, and if so, how would I call the parser file, just code it like this?

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
```

If not, what would be my options???? Thank you for your help :)
FOR the parser how would I specify the text file to be read on the command line. I have a

```
public static void main (String[] commandLineArgs)
```

how would I write a specific text file in this statement???? Would i replace the commandLineArgs? I forgot about this.

Comment: Have you been skipping class, all this time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourClass YourFile; // Need to fully qualified class name and full path for the file.
```

**EDIT** : If I understand correctly, you need something like this :

```
public class Parser {

    public void parseFile (String file) {
       // parsing code goes here.
    }
    public static void main (String[] commandLineArgs) {
         Parser parser = new Parser();
         parser.parseFile(commandLineArgs[0]);   //  
    }

}
```